# What material can be used as scraper in a chemical reactor?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, polymers, materials

I am having a 10L reactor built using SS316 for Plastic Pyrolysis.

TEMPERATURE : 550C

I would like a scraper to clean the char that forms on the reactor's inner layer.

[image: Picture showing reactor with teflon scraper]

Teflon scraper is available but it will not withstand 550C temperature.

So I am thinking about using flexible expanded graphite (Similar to graphite gland packing ropes) material. What do you think?

[image: graphite gland ropes]

What other options do you suggest that I look into?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by scraper. What does it look like? Is it part of the reactor's stirrer whose role other than mixing is to shif the char that deposits at the sides of the reactor while in operation? Cant you use steel?

Comment: @vanadium My question is why are you not doing this in a continuous reactor to reduce char? The high temperature would lend itself well to this, especially if the plastic is melted. If it's milled/ chipped, there are continuous options for this too.

Comment: @AMM  Scraper is to remove the character which is formed in the vessel. It should make contact with the vessel to remove char effectively. In the picture, Teflon is used as scraper blade. Steel blade cannot be used as it will damage the reactors inner wall.

Comment: @Beerhunter I did consider having a plastic screw extruder and heating the extruder barrel to 550C. But am not sure on how effective it will be. Please do let me know if you can share more information about the continuous process.

Comment: I'm sure you can hire twin screw extruders for a trial. You might need to give it a heat boost (induction?) as the hottest I've seen is 300ish degrees C. The simplest method would be to melt/soften in a twin screw and pump into the subsequent high temp reactor for the pyrolysis step.

Comment: @Vanadium Ok, i see what you mean. So the scraper is the plastic dressed steel plates attached to the stirrer in the picture, correct? There are plastics around that can take such temperatures: https://www.professionalplastics.com/MELDIN7001 for example but looks too cumbersome and expensive to make such modification. I would try using bronze or any other soft metal instead of steel which shouldnt damage the reacton being a softer metal. Cant guarranty this would work though as i have never tried with the steel reactors i work with.